# Symfony demo app install fails - pdo_sqlite missing

Tags: composer-php, symfony4, phpbrew

I am trying to use the Symfony 4 demo application https://github.com/symfony/demo but when I install it with composer I get the error described below.  I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and php 7.1 installed via phpbrew.

My steps are as follows:

```
$ cd /var/www/html
$ phpbrew use php-7.1.13
$ sudo php composer.phar create-project symfony/symfony-demo
```

which yields this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
- The requested PHP extension ext-pdo_sqlite * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's pdo_sqlite extension.
```

if I check which extensions are loaded:

```
$ phpbrew extension
```

I get

```
Loaded extensions:
...
[*] pdo_sqlite
```

so it appears that extension is loaded.

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: If your issue still actual, please provide output of `phpbrew --debug ext install pdo_sqlite` and `phpbrew info | grep sqlite` after reloading apache service.

Answer (score 8):

just do:

> sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite

In ubuntu 16.04 there is no php5-sqlite. You need:

> sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite
>
> sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: and? Topic starter asked about `phpbrew` usage, not about PHP installed in system.

Answer (score 3):

Symfony on Google Cloud App Engine standard environment for PHP 7.2

Following [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-symfony-on-appengine-standard) tutorial.

It worked like this :

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-sqlite
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
composer update
cd my_symfony_directory
php bin/console server:run
```

The installation of sqlite & mbstring it depends on the version of PHP you are using.

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu 16.04, just do:

```
sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3
sudo service apache2 restart
cd symfony-demo/
php bin/console server:run
```

It works for me